# Deploy Django 2.1 with Apache and mod_wsgi gives Timeout

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I´m really stuck trying to get my Django-App 2.1 (Python3) working with Apache2 and mod_wsgi.
Maybe some good people here can help me out?

I had to put my VHost for 80 and 443 into one file, since certbot is only doing Copy & Paste with the VHost and that leads to an error due to the requirement of the unique WSGI Process naming etc.

So here is my VHost (apache2 configtest all good):

```
 WSGIDaemonProcess my.domain.co processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/var/www/site/project/venv/lib/python3.6
 WSGIProcessGroup my.domain.co
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/site/project/wsgi.py
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName my.domain.co
 DocumentRoot /var/www/site

 <directory /var/www/site>
   AllowOverride all
   Require all granted
   Options FollowSymlinks
 </directory>

 Alias /static/ /var/www/site/static/

 <Directory /var/www/site/static>
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =my.domain.co
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName my.domain.co
 DocumentRoot /var/www/site

 <directory /var/www/site>
   AllowOverride all
   Require all granted
   Options FollowSymlinks
 </directory>

 Alias /static/ /var/www/site/project/

 <Directory /var/www/site/static>
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
SSLCertificateFile ...
SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Where my projectstructure is obviously: 
/var/www/site as the main directory in which the venv lives and django-project was created. The project dir contains the wsgi.py and the settings.py.

So when I´m trying to open my site I´m running into a timeout error.
When I´m doing: python3 manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080 and put a reverse proxy on it, it works - but thats of course not how it should work.

Does anyone have an idea what I´m missing out? :/

Thanks for any help, really appreciated!

EDIT:

LOG:

```
Current thread 0x00007f8064915bc0 (most recent call first):
[Sun Oct 14 06:28:55.988638 2018] [core:notice] [pid 47497] AH00051: child pid 36608 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

ERROR:

524

Comment: what is the exact timeout error? and what do your apache logs say?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added the log and error code to the question! :)

Comment: Pythonversion venv is 3.6 btw